# Can I find if an input field contains a numeric value in Javascript

Tags: javascript, input-field

I'm trying to validate a form field and am new to javascript. I have been using !isNaN but this only seems to detect if there is absolutely no numbers. For example, in the below example if I have 'Willy, Fred5' entered into the input field it seems to detect the strings and does not return false. What I need to do is detect if there is even one numeric value in the input field. But can't seem to find an answer that works.

```
function fnCheckName(strName) {
    strName.style.background = "#FFFFFF";
    var nameChk = strName.value;
    if (nameChk.indexOf(', ') < 0 || nameChk == "" || !isNaN(nameChk){
        strName.style.background = "#FBEC5D";
        return false}
        else {return true}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082/validate-decimal-numbers-in-javascript-isnumeric

Comment: try regexp class in JavaScript and create a regular expression for it.

Comment: Nice comedy, falcon... that links to a question marked as a duplicate!

Comment: @Jeremy, corrected before you responded

Comment: Still doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Appart from the *if* condition having a syntax error, `!isNaN(nameChk)` will return true only if [*isNaN*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.2.4) returns false, i.e. *nameChk* **is** a number (or can be coerced to a number).

Comment: @RobG `!isNaN("foo1bar")` returns false, but the OP expressed interest to "detect if there is even one numeric value in the input field". (Some languages/libraries would have accepted such a conversion to a number as 1.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/\d/.test('foo5')
outputs: true

/\d/.test('foo')
outputs: false

/\d/.test('5')
outputs: true
```

So given those inputs and outputs, I think your modified code would be:

```
function fnCheckName(strName) {
  strName.style.background = "#FFFFFF";
  var nameChk = strName.value;
  if (nameChk.indexOf(', ') < 0 || nameChk == "" || !/\d/.test(nameChk)) {
    strName.style.background = "#FBEC5D";
    return false
  }
  else {
    return true
  }
}
```

Comment: I think the OP want's the inverse (really non-negated) test form for "contains a digit".. but using `/\d/` (or equivalent) is suitable for the task.

Comment: I couldn't really tell, the question is pretty unclear. If they want the inverse then they can remove the !.

Comment: Thanks for that. yes needed to take out the ! but it worked thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add RegExp:

```
function fnCheckName(strName) {
strName.style.background = "#FFFFFF";
var nameChk = strName.value;
if (/\d/.test(nameChk)){
        strName.style.background = "#FBEC5D";
        return false
    }
    else {return true}
```

/^[a-zA-Z]+$/ - checks for only letters (true for "fdsfjklr")

/^([^0-9]*)$/ - checks for only numbers (true for "4321")

/\d/  - checks for any string with number (true for "fdslkj45")

Answer (score 0):

Try this Danrex

```
function fnCheckName(strName) {
    strName.style.background = "#FFFFFF";
    var nameChk = strName.value;
    var regNew = new RegExp(/^([^0-9]*)$/);
    if (regNew.test(nameChk)) {//If true i.e. no digit is in the string

    } else {//If false i.e. digit is in the string  

    }
}
```

or

```
function fnCheckName(strName) {
        strName.style.background = "#FFFFFF";
        var nameChk = strName.value;
        var regNew = new RegExp(/^([^0-9]*)$/);
        return (regNew.test(nameChk));
    };
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this changes,

```
function fnCheckName(strName) {
strName.style.background = "#FFFFFF";
var nameChk = strName.value;
var status = false;
for(var i=0;i<nameChk.length;i++){
  if(isNan(nameChk[i])==false)
    status = true;
  else
    status = false;
}
return status;
}
```

Comment: I keep getting an error - uncaught type error - undefined is not a function on the if() line.

Comment: [`isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) is a global function, not a Number method .. also a break/return is missing, so even with the isNaN change this is only "true" if the *last* character is not-NaN.

Comment: It's still wrong because of a missing break/return - status will be reset because the loop is not terminated correctly. Try with the values "1foo" and "bar2" as both of these contain numbers, but this function will only return true in one case. (This is also a very curious use of `isNaN`, although I believe it holds that `!isNaN(x) === /\d/.test(x)` for all single-character strings x ..)

Answer (score -1):

If you enter even one number return false else return true

```
eval('/^[a-zA-Z]+$/').test('sfjd');
```

**EDIT**

```
function fnCheckName(strName) {
        if( eval('/^[a-zA-Z]+$/').test(strName))
        {
            // this name not contains numbers
            // change background or every things that you want
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            // this name has number or numbers
            // change background or every things that you want
            return false;

        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't even know how to put this in or what it is?

Comment: The use of `eval` is *"just wrong"* (it will actually have equivalent semantics if removed so `eval` is *entirely unnecessary and useless* here). That aside, this will fail and return "true" for input like `=^_^=`.